# Inverse Matrix (Numpy) int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, overflow, matrix-inverse

I am trying to take the inverse of a 365x365 matrix. Some of the values get as large as 365**365 and so they are converted to long numbers. I don't know if the `linalg.matrix_power()` function can handle long numbers. I know the problem comes from this (because of the error message and because my program works just fine for smaller matrices) but I am not sure if there is a way around this. The code needs to work for a NxN matrix.

Here's my code:

```
item=0
for i in xlist:
    xtotal.append(arrayit.arrayit(xlist[item],len(xlist)))
    item=item+1
print xtotal
xinverted=numpy.linalg.matrix_power(xtotal,-1)
coeff=numpy.dot(xinverted,ylist)
```

`arrayit.arrayit`:

```
def arrayit(number, length):
    newarray=[]
    import decimal
    i=0
    while i!=(length):
        newarray.insert(0,decimal.Decimal(number**i))
        i=i+1
    return newarray;
```

The program is taking x,y coordinates from a list (list of x's and list of y's) and makes a function. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Decimal(365**365)`

Comment: Can you describe your use case? These are some stupendously huge numbers.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that `numpy.linalg.matrix_power` (but consider using `numpy.linalg.inv` instead!) will only work on numbers that can fit into a `double` or `long double`. I don't think it's specialised on general objects like `decimal.Decimal`. If you can scale your entire matrix by a constant so it's reasonable you should have more luck (it doesn't look like you can in your case though...).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah I tried that but the `numpy.linalg.matrix_power` function converts everything to float, and @DavidW I think I might have to factor out a constant. @user2357112 The program will fit a polynomial function to n set of points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might try is the library [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/), which can do simple matrix algebra and other such problems on arbitrary precision numbers.

**A couple of caveats:** It will almost certainly be slower than using numpy, and, as Lutzl points out in [his answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29875756/4657412), the problem may well not be mathematically well defined. Also, you need to decide on the precision you want before you start.

Some brief example code,

```
from mpmath import mp, matrix

# set the precision - see http://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html#setting-the-precision
mp.prec = 5000 # set it to something big at the cost of speed.
   # Ideally you'd precalculate what you need.
   # a quick trial with 100*100 showed that 5000 works and 500 fails

# see the documentation at http://mpmath.org/doc/current/matrices.html
# where xtotal is the output from arrayit
my_matrix = matrix(xtotal) # I think this should work. If not you'll have to create it and copy

# do the inverse
xinverted = my_matrix**-1
coeff = xinverted*matrix(ylist)
# note that as lutlz pointed out you really want to use solve instead of calculating the inverse. 
# I think this is something like
from mpmath import lu_solve
coeff = lu_solve(my_matrix,matrix(ylist))
```

I suspect your real problem is with the maths rather than the software, so I doubt this will work fantastically well for you, but it's always possible!

Comment: Thank you! I actually do have the entire calculation coded in it was just that the numpy library didn't support. It has been over a year and half so it may be different now. Sorry for the late response I was sleeping. :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever hear of Lagrange or Newton interpolation? This would avoid the whole construction of the VanderMonde matrix. But not the potentially large numbers in the coefficients.

---

As a general observation, you do not want the inverse matrix. You do not need to compute it. What you want is to solve a system of linear equations.

```
x = numpy.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

solves the system `A*x=b`.

---

You (really) might want to look up the **Runge effect**. Interpolation with equally spaced sample points is an increasingly ill-conditioned task. Useful results can be obtained for single-digit degrees, larger degrees tend to give wildly oscillating polynomials.

---

You can often use polynomial regression, i.e., approximating your data set by the best polynomial of some low degree.